# Store associative array in database using serialize in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, serialization, associative-array

I already asked this before and now I know how to serialize it. But now the problem is I am having this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''address1t', 'address2t', 'cityt', 'provincet', 'postalCODEt', 'contactNOt', 'em' at line 1
```

This is my associative array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [recNAME] => NAME1 [company] => [address1] => ADDRESS1 [address2] => [city] => CITY1 [province] => PROVINCE1 [postalCODE] => 0 [contactNO] => 926XXXXX [email] => XXXXX@yahoo.com [commodity] => COMMODITY1 [type] => [weight] => 0 [length] => 0 [width] => 0 [height] => 0 [decVAL] => 0 [specINSTRUC] => [shipREF] => REF1 [payMETHOD] => CashOnDelivery [packNO] => 200XXXX-XXX [trackNO] => 200XXXX-XXX ) [1] => Array ( [recNAME] => NAME2 [company] => [address1] => ADDRESS2 [address2] => [city] => CITY2 [province] => PROVINCE2 [postalCODE] => 0 [contactNO] => 905XXXXXX [email] => XXXXX@hotmail.com [commodity] => COMMODITY2 [type] => [weight] => 0 [length] => 0 [width] => 0 [height] => 0 [decVAL] => 361 [specINSTRUC] => I'm in the above given address from M-F, 11AM-6PM, call or text me for confirmation [shipREF] => 200XXXXX [payMETHOD] => CashOnDelivery [packNO] => 200XXXX-XXX [trackNO] => 200XXXX-XXX ) )
```

And the serialized array looks like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;a:21:{s:7:"recNAME";s:18:" NAME1";s:7:"company";s:0:"";s:8:"address1";s:57:"ADDRESS1";s:8:"address2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:8:"CITY1";s:8:"province";s:8:"PROVINCE1";s:10:"postalCODE";s:1:"0";s:9:"contactNO";s:10:"9XXXXXXXX";s:5:"email";s:21:"XXXX@yahoo.com";s:9:"commodity";s:13:"COMMODITY1";s:4:"type";s:0:"";s:6:"weight";s:1:"0";s:6:"length";s:1:"0";s:5:"width";s:1:"0";s:6:"height";s:1:"0";s:6:"decVAL";s:2:"99";s:11:"specINSTRUC";s:0:"";s:7:"shipREF";s:9:"200XXXX";s:9:"payMETHOD";s:14:"CashOnDelivery";s:6:"packNO";s:14:"200XXXX-XXX";s:7:"trackNO";s:14:"200XXXX-XXX";}i:1;a:21:{s:7:"recNAME";s:32:" NAME2";s:7:"company";s:0:"";s:8:"address1";s:52:"ADDRESS1";s:8:"address2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:6:"CITY2";s:8:"province";s:12:"PROVINCE2";s:10:"postalCODE";s:1:"0";s:9:"contactNO";s:10:"9XXXXXX";s:5:"email";s:23:"XXXX@hotmail.com";s:9:"commodity";s:7:"Spyder ";s:4:"type";s:0:"";s:6:"weight";s:1:"0";s:6:"length";s:1:"0";s:5:"width";s:1:"0";s:6:"height";s:1:"0";s:6:"decVAL";s:3:"361";s:11:"specINSTRUC";s:83:"I'm in the above given address from M-F, 11AM-6PM, call or text me for confirmation";s:7:"shipREF";s:9:"200XXXXX";s:9:"payMETHOD";s:14:"CashOnDelivery";s:6:"packNO";s:14:"200XXXX-XXX";s:7:"trackNO";s:14:"200XXXX-XXX";}}
```

And this is my code on serializing it:

```
$newstring = serialize($array);
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp` (`recNAMEt`, `companyt`, 'address1t', 'address2t', 'cityt', 'provincet', 'postalCODEt', 'contactNOt', 'emailt', 'commodityt', 'typet', 'weightt', 'lengtht', 'widtht', 'heightt', 'decVALt', 'specINSTRUCt', 'shipREFt', 'payMETHODt', 'packNOt', 'trackNOt' ) VALUES('', $newstring)") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

This is my first time to serialize and I am still getting a handle on things. I still don't know what went wrong because this code worked for a normal array. I tried doing this:

```
VALUES('', '', $newstring)")
```

still no luck. The recNAMEt, companyt, etc are column names in my table. Please help. Thanks and regards.

Comment: You cannot do it like this. Read documentation about: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I saw it here: https://www.namepros.com/webmaster-tutorials/281176-php-using-serialize-handle-store-arrays.html. I'm learning on how to use serialize in storing array to my database.

Comment: It's tutorial how to store any data inside one field.

Comment: ow. I think that's why it's not working. thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong @nicole

First of all serialize convert's an array into string

So there are two way's  for

a)  Have a single column in the database and insert the serialized array in that column \

For example:

```
Instead of this

  @mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp` (`recNAMEt`, `companyt`, 'address1t', 'address2t', 'cityt', 'provincet', 'postalCODEt', 'contactNOt', 'emailt', 'commodityt', 'typet', 'weightt', 'lengtht', 'widtht', 'heightt', 'decVALt', 'specINSTRUCt', 'shipREFt', 'payMETHODt', 'packNOt', 'trackNOt' ) VALUES('', $newstring)") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 


    You can have

  @mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp` (`details` ) VALUES($newstring)") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

and later own when you fetch the result from database unserailzed the value & you will get back you array

b) This is bit more tricky but will solve the purpose of your's
     this will generate your query

```
             $sql = sprintf(
              'INSERT INTO `temp`(%s) VALUES ("%s")',
               implode(',',array_keys($_newstring )),
               implode('","',array_values($_newstring ))
              );
            mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: ow ok. so serialize is use in saving an array in one column. What Im trying to do is save the datas in the array to the corresponding table columns. I guess I'll find another way then. I'll try (b). Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there is a form with multiple checkboxes and user can select more than one checkbox at a time, then we need to store those values in array format in a single column of the table.

Look at the below code snippet to see how this can be done in only few line of code-:)

HTML Code

```
<form action="path_to_action_page" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="value[]" value="value1">Value1
<input type="checkbox" name="value[]" value="value2">Value2
<input type="checkbox" name="value[]" value="value3">Value3
<input type="checkbox" name="value[]" value="value4">Value4
<input type="checkbox" name="value[]" value="value5">Value5
```

PHP Code to retrieve the form data:-

```
$data= $_POST['value'];
$values= serialize($data);
```

Code to insert the data in database:-

//code for database connection

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(col_name) VALUES('$values')";
$result_insert = mysql_query($insert_query);
```

Code to retrieve the values from database:-

```
$query = "SELECT col_name FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE condition_to_search_the_database";


$result = mysql_query($query);
 while($values = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


$values= unserialize($values['col_name']);



  foreach($values as $value)


 {
  //code to play with $value
  e.g. - print $value;


 }}
```